# How to improve my animation and make it even (Jetpack Compose)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to fire some Boxes regularly from bottom to top. I have almost managed to achieve this but for some reason my Boxes are not spaced evenly, as you can see from the gif. My feeling is that my code is not the best way to achieve what I am trying to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
listOf(
        Color(0xffDFFF00),
        Color(0xffFFBF00),
        Color(0xffFF7F50),
        Color(0xffDE3163),
        Color(0xff9FE2BF),
        Color(0xff40E0D0),
        Color(0xff6495ED),
        Color(0xffCCCCFF),
    ).forEachIndexed { index, color ->
        val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
        val positionState = infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 0f,
            targetValue = 1f,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(
                    durationMillis = 2500,
                    delayMillis = delay,
                    easing = LinearEasing
                )
            )
        )
        delay += 1000
        val modifier = Modifier.offset(
            x = (maxWidth - tileSize),
            y = maxHeight - (maxHeight * positionState.value),
        )
       Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .size(tileSize)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                .background(color = color)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                style = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
            )
        }
```

Here is the gif:

[image: Uneven boxes]

PS: Having now tried the accepted answer, it doesn't work as expected. Please see comment below. Thanks!

Comment: There are some issues. If you are using a `Column`, each `Box` starts with a different h position. You should consider it in the offset modifier, otherwise use a `Box` as parent. Then since you are using an infinite loop you should consider that the first item starts again the animation before all other items finish the animation and it overlaps the other boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using a Column but a BoxWithConstraints. But yes, maybe the infinite loop is causing the problem. I'll try and work it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `delay` is also being repeated in the `infiniteRepeatable`. In other words, **the animations that were 1000ms apart in the first iteration become 2000ms apart in the second iteration.**

Non-repeating delays are not yet support in infinite transition. Here I would recommend using `Animatable` to achieved the staggered infinite animation.

```
...
forEachIndexed { index, color ->
    val positionAnimation = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    LaunchedEffect(positionAnimation) {
        delay(1000 * index) // this delay increases with the index
        launch {
            positionAnimation.animateTo(
                1f,
                animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                    animation = tween(
                        durationMillis = 2500, // remove the delay from infinite repeatable
                        easing = LinearEasing
                    )
                )
            )
        }
     }
...
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for days!

Comment: So I've just tried the code and what happens is that there is an 8 second pause at the beginning and then only the 8th Box (the purple one) travels upwards. Any ideas? @Doris Liu

Comment: It may be that the amount of `delay` stored in `delay` var kept growing and never got reset. What if you try `delay(1000 * index)` instead? See the new edits.